# DetailPrint not working in nsDialogs page function

Tags: nsis

I have created a patch script where I have three sections but I need to run this only if the currently installed version is say '3.1'. So I have created a custom Page where I can go and check the current version - if it is indeed '3.1' I go and install the patch, otherwise I skip all sections. But DetailPrint in the page function never prints out. Can anyone suggested any other way to solve this simple problem?

```
Name nsDialogs
OutFile nsDialogs.exe

XPStyle on

Page custom checkInstalledVersion 
Page instfiles

Function checkInstalledVersion
     ; perform some checking to get the currently installed version
     DetailPrint "You cannot install the patch on this version."
FunctionEnd

Section

DetailPrint "hello world"

SectionEnd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me [quote](http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?p=1853845#post1853845) one of developers to answer your question:

> `DetailPrint` prints to the install log window. That window is only
>   available when the `instfiles` page is reached. Sections are executed
>   when the `instfiles` page shows, and that's why you [only] see `DetailPrint` [when] used in sections.

You can use a `MessageBox` instead.